# OpenAPI generator jaxrs-spec stop shorterning my enum values

Tags: java, enums, jax-rs, openapi, openapi-generator

Given this OpenAPI specification for the `sizeRange` field of a **Project** model:

```yaml
size:
  type: string
  description: Size range for this project
  enum: [RANGE_0_10M,RANGE_10M_50M,RANGE_50M_100M]
  example: RANGE_10M_50M
```

The `jaxrs-spec` OpenAPI generator results in a **Project.class** like:

```java
public enum SizeEnum {
_0_10M(String.valueOf("RANGE_0_10M")), _10M_50M(String.valueOf("RANGE_10M_50M")), _50M_100M(String.valueOf("RANGE_50M_100M"));
```

The resulting enum values are shortened (for use in Java):

```java
Project.SizeEnum._0_10M
```

I was prepared to ignore this inconvenience, but it's resulting in an exception in this case:

```java
Enum.valueOf(Project.SizeEnum.class, "RANGE_0_10M");

No enum constant com.mycompany.my_project.Project.SizeEnum.RANGE_0_10M
```

#### Notes

If I add a value into the enum that begins with something other than `RANGE_` this causes all of the enum values to appear correctly. I infer that some process is automagically shortening all of them because they share a prefix.

***Is this an OpenAPI generator configuration I have access to?*** I can't find it:

- https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/configuration/
- https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/jaxrs-spec

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of your unwanted `RANGE_` prefix by **adding the flag** `removeEnumValuePrefix=false` to the `additionalProperties` part of your OpenAPI generator `configuration`.

---

### Complete example (maven):

```
<execution>
    <id>generate-id</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <additionalProperties>
            removeEnumValuePrefix=false
        </additionalProperties>
        <inputSpec>spec.yaml</inputSpec>
        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
        <configOptions>
            <identifierNamingConvention>snake_case</identifierNamingConvention>
        </configOptions>
        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/output</output>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```